# visual studio code regex - Search and Replace in folders - use filename in replace

Tags: visual-studio-code

Maybe I'm looking in the wrong places, but what I'm looking for is to use the file name in the regex replacing function, but I'm simply unable to find the regex instruction.
thank you

Comment: To get the filename you can right-click on its tab and choose `Copy Path` or `Copy Relative Path`.  Is that what you were looking for?  Otherwise, there is no variable available to use in the replace field.  But you could probably do what you want in a snippet which does have access to variables like `${file}` for the current file for example.  But you can't run snippets over multiple files at once, if that is what you are doing.

Comment: Thank you Mark. Unfortunately, i need to batch edit part of the code of all scripts in a folder adding a part of the file name. I'm really surprised that is not possible to use the file name, among the millions of elements one can use...

Comment: Are any of the variables at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_predefined-variables what you want for the part of the filename?  I am thinking of adding the ability to use those variables in the find or replace field to an extension that I wrote:  https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform

Comment: Hello Mark, sorry for the delay. I'd say "${fileBasenameNoExtension}". I need to basically use the first part of the filename to modify part of the code. But I need to do it on all the files in a certain folder. Have a nice day.

Comment: Do you need the filename resolved for each file in the folder separately?  So each replace in each file is different based on that particular filename?  That is much tougher than using the current filename for all replacements.  I have written an extension `Find and Transform` which can parts of the filename in the replacement but not each different filename.